# Best way to store data for machine learning (Database or Files)

Tags: database-design, sql, machine-learning

I am currently in the process of developing a machine learning application, where my users can upload their own data to train models. Furthermore, the users must be able to extend their uploaded data with new data (append new data to it). I am in a bit of doubt when it comes to actually store this (and whether or not it should be in a DB)

The data source can be:

- CSV file
- Excel file

As each file is unique, the column names will also be dynamic. For example, see below:

```php
// File_1.csv
comment
----------
Some text here
another text here
```

```php
// File_1.xlsx
ingredient
----------
tomato
strawberry
```

At some point, after the data has been uploaded, the user should be able to extend it (append new data to it). For example:

```php
// File_1 data:
text added at a later date
```

## Labels

Now, after the data has been uploaded for each model, a user must be able to add labels to it (for example for text classification). For simplicity, let's assume that we have two labels: `label_one` and `label_two`.

In order to store this, I was thinking of creating a table called `model_data`.

[image]

Inside this table, I would, for each model, save the data in the `data` column (in JSON). Something like:

```
{
   "rows":[
      {
         "text":"Some text here",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":true,
               "label_two":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"Another text here",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":true,
               "label_two":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"tomato",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":false,
               "label_two":true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"strawberry",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":false,
               "label_two":true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"text added at a later date",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":false,
               "label_two":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Is this even a feasible way to store such data? Typically, data for ML tasks often consists of large datasets with thousands of rows.

## Alternative

I have also considered just using a filesystem to maintain this, and then store data for each model in a CSV file. So whenever a user uploads some data (and extends it), it will be added to a new CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Training data is mostly of the write-once, read-bulk kind, which can be handled with flat files easily. Even appending new data to existing files is absolutely no problem. As long as you don't need updating or deletion of rows or selection according to criteria that are best handled in a relational database there's really no reason to use a database for the training data.

However, you might want to store metadata about the datasets in a database where it is more easily accessible to data management tools.

Comment: I would want users to classify (label) their existing data, thus needing to update/delete specific rows in the CSV / Excel file.

Comment: Incidentally, Tensorflow takes input data and labels in separate inputs, so it would make sense to have append-only data CSVs and updatable label CSVs that are just read and written as a whole when updated.

Comment: Ah, I see. How would you match the CSV file containing the data with the CSV file containing the labels? For example, if you remove a line from the data CSV file, it should also be removed from the label CSV file.

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to support editing of the data or just treat it as static with possible additions. If you don't know, try to find out, you're still at the requirements analysis stage. If you know that users will edit training data, then choose a database (with all associated overhead).

Comment: The users will be editing training data (accepting / discarding data for training). However, as the data files are used uploaded, they are also dynamic - the columns will vary. So I cannot see how this can be stored in a database?

Comment: You've painted yourself in a corner :-) Handling a dynamic schema in relational databases isn't easy, and you  must decide whether you want to implement that just to provide editing capabilities. In your post, you mentioned only uploading and appending, which is easily done with flat files. Are the editing requirements essential? Then your project has just grown quite a bit in complexity.

Comment: Very good point and this shows the frustration that often comes in software engineering. Also quite fun! They are essential, as the users need to be able to "mark" the data that should be used for model training and the data that should be discarded as well as assign the correct label(s).

What about keeping the flat file structure, but transforming the uploaded files - maybe adding an `id` to each line? Then access the line(s) by that `id`. Not sure about the performance hit though.